# LTC1707 Buck regulator Vout signal ground confusion

Tags: analog, buck

I am using the LTC1707 buck regulator to step down from ~6V (4 aa alkaline cells) to 5V. I am confused about proper grounding. Initially I used a common ground and this caused Vout to be 6V when Vin was 6V so I knew I did something wrong. Then I re-read the datasheet PC board layout checklist where it mentioned segregating signal and power grounds. I probed Vout and R4 and sure enough it showed 5V. I did this on a breadboard but now I'm going to solder it more permanently. Should I be using this point on the resistive divider (R4 lead) to ground the rest of the circuit that will be using the 5V Vout? Also I'm unsure about the star ground formation. I gather it's when a single point connects the ground planes. So Since R3 is connected to power ground does this complete the star ground formation?
[image: modified schematic]

Comment: that symbol hurts my eyes

Comment: I was going to do it in KiCad but this way is more obvious

Comment: your cct aligns with figure8 (with a suitable resistor change) so that is ok. Do NOT do what you have in red, that will set the feedback to zero and will blow the switcher up. check you connections, you will have a mistake somewhere

Comment: Okay I won't do that then. I've checked all the connections multiple times. I soldered this to a DIP adapter and checked for continuity between all the pins. Maybe I broke the IC somehow. I'm not sure what dumb mistake I made but the output voltage remains unchanged except if I do what I described